# EC2 instance running not accessible

Tags: amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I'm running a master server on an EC2 linux instance with code deploy running a spring boot app.
I can ssh to the instance and i can see that the application is up and running, but i can't ping or hit the api. i set it up the same as i did our development server that is accessible.
the only thing i see is different is the subnet. is that to do with that and can i change it after the instance is up already?

The rules are open for all, there is a public ip.

i have tried noting, Not quite sure what to do, help would be welcome!

Thanks

Comment: 1. Does the instance have a public IP address assigned to it? 2. Is the port you are trying to hit open on the security group, to the IP address you are trying to hit it from?

Comment: Thanks, see my edit. But yeah, rules are open to all and it has a public ip

Comment: The rules are never all open on EC2's nor should they be, and almost no one allows IMCP (ping) traffic though to a public URL.   Are you using the IP to connect or the EC2 host?   If you are using the IP are you sure it is the public IP and not the internal AWS IP?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out my security group wasn't open for all after all... so that was the issue. Thanks